# Can't convert .py script that uses python-docx into .exe

Tags: python, exe, pyinstaller, docx, cx-freeze

Im using Python 3.6 and I wrote a script in which the user enters data through `tkinter GUI` and it gets then printed along with some extra text into a WORD doc.

All works fine in my Wing IDE but once it comes to converting it to `.exe` it either shows mistakes when I use `py2exe` / `cx_Freeze` or just opens and instantly closes the window when I convert it with `pyinstaller`.

When I try to convert the script containing standad libraries and tkinter it works perfectly fine. But once I include `docx` it just doesnt want to work for some reason. As I am aware now the Pyinstaller does not want to work with `docx`. Is there any other ways I can convert my script containing `docx` into `.exe` ?

Also, Im pretty new to programming. Thanks in advance.

Here's a short example:

```
from tkinter import *
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches

document = Document('CRS-example.docx')

def Generate(event):
    document.add_paragraph('Hello World')
    document.save('TESTING.docx')

root = Tk()

frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()
generate = Button(frame, text = 'Generate')
generate.bind('<Button-1>', Generate)
generate.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

On top of that the cx_Freeze gives me such list of mistakes:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setupcx.py", line 18, in <module>
    executables = [Executable("tkinter_test.py", base = base)])
  File "C:\Development\Python\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py", line 349, in setup
    distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "C:\Development\Python\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Development\Python\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Development\Python\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Development\Python\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "C:\Development\Python\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Development\Python\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Development\Python\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py", line 219, in run
    freezer.Freeze()
  File "C:\Development\Python\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 616, in Freeze
    self.finder = self._GetModuleFinder()
  File "C:\Development\Python\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 340, in _GetModuleFinder
    finder.IncludeModule(name)
  File "C:\Development\Python\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 651, in IncludeModule
    namespace = namespace)
  File "C:\Development\Python\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 311, in _ImportModule
    deferredImports, namespace = namespace)
  File "C:\Development\Python\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 404, in _InternalImportModule
    parentModule, namespace)
  File "C:\Development\Python\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 417, in _LoadModule
    namespace)
  File "C:\Development\Python\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 486, in _LoadPackage
    self._LoadModule(name, fp, path, info, deferredImports, parent)
  File "C:\Development\Python\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 464, in _LoadModule
    self._RunHook("load", module.name, module)
  File "C:\Development\Python\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 537, in _RunHook
    method(self, *args)
  File "C:\Development\Python\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\hooks.py", line 615, in load_tkinter
    tclSourceDir = os.environ["TCL_LIBRARY"]
  File "C:\Development\Python\lib\os.py", line 669, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'TCL_LIBRARY'
```

This is also my cx_Freeze setup.py in which I am getting above errors:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

build_exe_options = {"includes": ["tkinter"]}

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

setup(
    name = "simple_Tkinter",
    version = "0.1",
    description = "Sample cx_Freeze Tkinter script",
    options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
    executables = [Executable("tkinter_test.py", base = base)])
```

Comment: If you start the EXE from a command prompt, does it emit any error messages?

Comment: No. it works perfectly fine from command prompt.